# How can a cross-level interaction be random in a 2-level mixed-model?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I was wondering why `m` below is a legitimate model? If it is, what is the meaning of its random part?

`ses` is a level-1 predictor and `sector` a level-2 predictor making their combinations a cross-level interaction.

In other words, I'm asking how a cross-level interaction can be taken to be random in a 2-level model?

**UPDATE:** How about model `mm` with `sector` in the random part?

```
library(lme4)

hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

m <- lmer(math ~ ses*sector + (ses:sector | sch.id), data = hsb)  

mm <- lmer(math ~ ses+sector  + (sector | sch.id), data = hsb) #UPDATE
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to remember that an interaction is the product of the two variables.

For example if we have

```
sch.id  ses  sector
1        1     1
1        2     1
2        3     2
2        4     2
```

..then the interaction for `ses:sector` will be:

```
sch.id  ses  sector  ses:sector
1        1     1        1
1        2     1        2
2        3     2        6
2        4     2        8
```

So, although `sector` does not vary with `sch.id`, the interaction that includes it does, because the other variable, `ses`, does vary within school.

As such, there is no technical reason why random slopes for such an interaction cannot be included - however it would be odd to fit the first model in the OP - that is, a model with random slopes *only* for the interaction, since it is impossible to vary an interaction independently of both main effects - so a more appropriate model (provided it is supported by the data) is:

```
math ~ ses*sector + (ses + ses:sector | sch.id)
```

Comment: You can try to estimate that model, but it doesn't make much sense as Rob nicely showed in the answer to your previous question - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490919/visualizing-the-folly-of-fitting-random-slopes-for-variables-that-dont-vary-wit

Comment: Yes, that model would not make sense due to the presence `sector` in the random slopes part.